# local server: Use video title according to video id

Tags: php

I'm trying to make this work here,
when a user click on any of the id video links
i want that video to also be able to have it's unique title
according to the video and show it on the webpage?

```
//index.php
<div class="thumbnail">
<a href="video.php?id=video1" title="I'am video 1!">
<img src="/local/images/vid_01.jpg">
</a>

</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
<a href="video.php?id=video2" title="I'am video 2!">
<img src="/images/vid_02.jpg">
</a>

</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
<a href="video.php?id=video3" title="I'am video 3!">
<img src="/images/vid_03.jpg">
</a>
</div>

//video.php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$idTitle = $_GET['title];

<section id="video-php">
<iframe src="media/<?php echo $id?>.mp4"  allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div id="video-info">
<?php echo $idTitle ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with the same general approach you have, you can add a title to the link:

```
href="video.php?id=video2&idTitle=Hello%20World
```

then this should output 'Hello World'

```
<?php echo $idTitle ?>
```

Comment: NICE! it work!, @pherris where can i look up to to find what does %20 code means? 
I know the %20 means space but where can i find to replace symbo such as ! ' @ and such.

Comment: Try this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding e.g. a exclamation mark is `%21`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $videos = [['title' => 'I am title 1', 'video' => 'video_0.mp4']]; ?>
```

Puts all data into the above array.

```
href="video.php?id=0"
<?php $id = $_GET['id']; $video = isset($videos[$id]) ? $videos[$id] : ['title' => '', 'video' => '']; echo $video['title']; ?>
```

Comment: I try this and it didn't work. it did not show any video. it just echo mp4